# Using apalike and natbib in Lyx with author abbreviation as index

Tags: bibtex, lyx, natbib, apa-style

I'm using Lyx 2.1.2 and want to use the apalike citation style. I created a BibTEX generated Bibliography, added my bib file and set the style to apalike, which all worked so far.

But then I wanted to cite the authors name instead of the [#ID] but the Citation Dialog would not show the necessary options under "Citation Style" until I changed the citation style to Natbib in "Document Settings/Bibliography". Now I can cite just the author name, but all the citations switched from abbreviations to numbers ([Abramson, 1978] -> [1]). I tried the author-year natbib style but I don't like it.

I also tried quite a few other options but nothing seemed to help. All I actually want is author abbreviations instead of numbers and the possibility to cite just the author name. Is there any way to do that in Lyx?

Here is the generated LaTex Code for both cases. The only difference is the additional usepackage line at the two slightly different cite commands.

Using the Default Style I get "Some time ago, [Abramson, 1978] wrote a paper [Abramson, 1978]."

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=4cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\date{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some time ago, \cite{Abramson:78} wrote a paper \cite{Abramson:78}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

And using natbib I get: "Some time ago, Abramson wrote a paper [1]."

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=4cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\date{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some time ago, \citeauthor{Abramson:78} wrote a paper \citep{Abramson:78}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

But what I want to get is: "Some time ago, Abramson wrote a paper [Abramson, 1978]."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A reason why I don't recommend LyX is that doing simple things becomes painful. Can you show a short example of your document (as converted to LaTeX by LyX)?